# Remove unused parent records from a SQL database table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql

Tests performed in SQL Server 2012 reveal that the command `DELETE FROM dbo.TableName` halts and returns an error if removing even a single record in the table would lead to a foreign key violation.  No records are deleted.

- Assume that unused records are those which can be deleted without violating foreign key relationships.
- Assume that all records are uniquely identifiable through a non-nullable integer ID column.
- Assume that it's safe to ignore features that can cause side-effects, such as triggers or cascade deletes.
- Little else about the table, its records and relationships should be assumed.  (Ex:  Solutions should be generic within these parameters.)

Does there exist a solution for removing unused parent records in the form of:

1. SQL which will ignore errors for records which cause it, and successfully execute upon records which do not?
2. SQL which will perform a DELETE only upon a set of somehow-detected unused parent records?  (Easily done for a specific table where the FK relationships are known.  Less easily done *generically*.)
3. Server-side code which will perform an equivalent of the above solutions?

**Notes:**

- SQL solutions are preferable over ones which require C#, Python, Java, Ruby, etc.
- Cross-RDBMS solutions are preferable over RDBMS-specific solutions.

Please state the RDBMS your solution applies to and *has been tested* on.

Comment: I don't follow this comment: `SQL which will perform a DELETE only upon a set of somehow-detected orphan records? (Easily done for a specific table where the FK relationships are known. Less easily done generically.)` I would think that by definition a record could only be an orphan if it has some kind of foreign key relationship that for which the record in the foreign table was deleted (in which case it is always easy to select these records based on an OUTER JOIN). What do you mean by having this done generically?

Comment: In Oracle you can use the option `log errors into` together with the `DELETE` statement. The cross-dbms solution would be something like `delete from foo where id in (select ...)` where the sub-select would return the "orphaned" rows.

Comment: Mike Brant:  Most of the solutions I've seen are very specific to the record/table definition.  You must know every parent table of the current record.  A "generic solution" would be able to detect a record or table's foreign key relationships and only delete records which would not cause a foreign key violation. This is opposed to specifying each table the record may be related to manually and performing a join.

Comment: May I ask why?  You create a FK to restrict values.  Why do you need to purge the FK table of values not referenced?   What if the next insert is a value you purged and now the insert fails?

Comment: Blam:  The idea is actually to purge a table of records which are no longer referencing valid foreign keys.  We're deleting child, not parent entities.  These are orphaned records and no longer belong in the database.  If they were used in production, we would try and find their parent entity by the foreign key and it wouldn't exist.  As for why this kind of thing happens, the situations can vary - everything from test data, to immature applications, to DB schema changes, to DB schemas which permit 0..n relations rather than 1..n (which may be valid in the schema but not in the application).

Comment: How can you be deleting orphaned records if there are foreign keys in place?  By definition foreign keys prevent orphans.  But regardless, we can always delete the child records: foreign keys only stop us deleting parent records.  In short, your question is a bit of a mess.  please revise it with some sample data - before and after - which demonstrates what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Just how do you have a record that is not referecning valid foreign key?   You don't get an error foreign key violation on deleting a child.

Comment: APC & Blam:  In scenarios where the foreign key is permitted to be null in the database, but this is not desirable in an application.  You do receive errors on deletes if that child is also a parent in another relationship and dependencies exist.

Comment: So the table is both a child and a parent. You got that error based on deleting the parent not the child.  Again just how does the child have an invalid FK value?

Comment: Blam:  There are no invalid FK values.  If I understand your corrections, what we are saying now is something different.  Upon performing a DELETE FROM dbo.TableName, if removing a single parent would result in FK violations, the deletes don't occur.

Comment: Blam: Now to answer an earlier question of yours - "May I ask why? You create a FK to restrict values. Why do you need to purge the FK table of values not referenced? What if the next insert is a value you purged and now the insert fails?" - The inserts should never fail because in many applications, such as the one I have been working on, inserts aren't available for data which is non-existent.

Comment: Just a note on corrections to earlier comments - I misunderstood the original DB schema and had inversed parent/child terminology in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in this case is disable the fk constraints, if that doesn't work, I usually drop the constraints, clean your data, and then recreate the fk.

Here is a quick link on how to do it
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1376/disable-enable-drop-and-recreate-sql-server-foreign-keys/

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can use the `LOG ERRORS INTO` option:

Sample data setup:

```
create table parent (pid integer not null primary key);
create table child 
(
  cid integer not null primary key,
  pid integer not null references parent(pid)
);

insert into parent values (1);
insert into parent values (2);
insert into parent values (3);

insert into child values (1,1);
insert into child values (2,1);
insert into child values (3,2);
```

Create the table that will log all non-deletable rows:

```
begin
  DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG('PARENT', 'ERR_LOG_PARENT');
end;
/
```

Now run the delete:

```
delete from parent
log errors into err_log_parent ('delete test')
reject limit unlimited;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d379c/1

Manual for DBMS_ERRLOG: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_errlog.htm
Manual for the `LOG ERRORS` option: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8005.htm#CEGCHDJF

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic pill that will get you want you want on all platforms, but you can write one that can be adapted to just about any DBMS.  And yes, we did this on a SQL server production database.  It's not a single step process, but you could easily automate the second step with dynamic SQL or somesuch.

In re:

> You must know every parent table of the current record.

Yep, but you can write code that accounts for that.  Use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views (SQL Server, MySQL) or your DB's equivalent to generate your delete statements for the tables in question.  Then run the statements you've generated.

A good place to start would be INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS, and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE.

Answer (score 0):

If the row has a reference to a the PK then that delete will fail but it will continue.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @PK varchar(10);

PRINT '-------- Delete PK --------';

DECLARE delete_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT PK 
FROM PKstring
ORDER BY PK;

OPEN delete_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM delete_cursor 
INTO @PK

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DELETE PKstring where PK = @PK 

    FETCH NEXT FROM delete_cursor 
    INTO @PK
END 
CLOSE delete_cursor;
DEALLOCATE delete_cursor;
```

Comment: Great response.  I am unfamiliar with cursors so didn't think of using them.  I can see how this example would be preferred over the one I posted.

Comment: So, then how is it not an answer?

Comment: It is an answer, like several others posted to this question.